# I tried to install Apache2 on Raspberry Pi and I lost sudo privileges

Tags: raspberry-pi, apache2, sudo

Newbie to raspberry pi and linux here.

I needed to install apache2 to my raspberry pi as a part of my homework and I lost privileges on `sudo`.

I first ran

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo service apache2 start
sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults
```

Then I ran following commands.

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R 775 var/www
```

After the last line, anytime I am trying anything on terminal it gives me an error message saying that
sudo: etc/sudo.conf is group writable.
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

I have tried various methods I found online but nothing worked.
Can you please help me? Thank you!

Anytime I am trying su - it asks for my password. I am entering my password but it does not recognize me and says my password is wrong. When I enter `passwd` and check my password again, it shows that my password is correct. I don't know what to do. If the password for `su -` is different than the one at `passwd`, then how do I know that password? raspberrypi was set up by my teachers and I don't know if there was another password unfortunately.